# How to update open source software downloaded from GitHub

Tags: github

I use software from the GitHub repository [Klocman/Bulk-Crap-Uninstaller](https://github.com/Klocman/Bulk-Crap-Uninstaller/releases/tag/v5.6).

Which file should I download to update my software?

I have downloaded this software before but I'm scared of making a mess so I don't act.

I've only been around GitHub for a short time

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick a suitable file from the "Assets" section on the bottom of the release page. If you have *installed* the software before, you probably need the file ending in `...setup.exe`.

If you run it, usually an installer will guide you through the update, but there is not "standard" for this, so it's just a "best guess".

(I don't use or even know this software, so I cannot predict exactly what will happen.)